# Parse returned value with Regexp on SQL query result

Tags: mysql, regex

Following query returns form field from tb2.

```
SELECT  tb1.*, tb2.form
FROM    jj_books tb1
        INNER JOIN jj_users tb2
            ON tb1.book_id = tb2.book_id
GROUP BY data_id
```

Form field contains delimeted data (text^book1^booktitle~text^book2^booktitle2~text^book3^booktitle3~...) and i need to retrieve only one string (booktitle2) from it.

Is it possible to use preg_match (REGEXP) in query and how?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is the third `^`-delimited field in the second `-`-delimited field, use nested instances of `substring_index()`.  It will probably be a lot simpler than a REGEXP.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index